# Node-App-Architecture: where does express come into node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, express

I'm trying to teach myself how to use nodejs and building a webApp with it. In most examples I come around [expressJs](http://expressjs.com/) is used as webFrameWork. I tried to read about it, but I mostly find examples. I want to understand where *exactly* expressJs comes in when using nodejs.

I see how to create a helloworld-web-server with 'pure' node-js (http://howtonode.org/hello-node).

I also see how to make this with expressJs:
http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html

Is express simply kind of a wrapper to be able to avoid that http-boilerplate code? If so, to what extent should I use express and to which should I be using nodes-API? Is it simply used to do the routing? Or what else is there?

In the [Express-FAQs](http://expressjs.com/starter/faq.html) I saw it doesn't help to take care of the database and that no models are created using expressJs. So, when building an App with node and express how should I handle the data (users, posts, whatever,...)?

I tried to do a whole lot of reading, but I'm not having *a clear big-picture* at which point one layer of abstraction ends and where the next exactly starts. I mean I understand that expressJs is a webFrameWork that sits on the node webserver running on a V8-engine, however I am a bit confused of what the final app code should be architectured: do I kind of have intermixed nodeJs code with expressJs code in a single app.js? Or should I have specific files which require express and another one for the database which does not require it?

So now you understand what I mean with:
**Where does express come into node.js? What does it do for me which I don't get from 'pure' node and what should I not expect from it?**

Maybe my whole confusion comes because the whole thing is javascript and you don't have like these explicit 'language-barriers' which make things a bit more obvious (I'm thinking about the LAMP-stack for instance). Or is this exactly the way I'm supposed to think about javascript in general? Like the only thing which you actually get is a javascript-interpreter and everything else is lib that we can include and and expressJs simply has nodeJs as a dependency? I'm really sorry for being so fuzzy. I'm just trying to get my mental-model straight.

Comment: LAMP equivalent for Nodejs is MEAN stack - http://mean.io/#!/. Check it out, it may help you. ALSO: Linux = Node, Apache = Express, MYSQL = Mongoose, PHP = Angular. Obviously since it is ALL JS there is mental overlap (and angular is not a language, but a framework ontop of PHP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Is express simply kind of a wrapper to be able to avoid that http-boilerplate code?***

Yes

***If so, to what extent should I use express and to which should I be using nodes-API?***

All Request and Response handling should be done via Express. Also see how Express Router simplifies things when there are a lot of urls to be served in your app

***Is it simply used to do the routing? Or what else is there?***

Yes that's pretty much it. But that's the point. Do one thing but do it good.

***So, when building an App with node and express how should I handle the data (users, posts, whatever,...)?***

Take a look at [Loopback](https://loopback.io/)

***I am a bit confused of what the final app code should be architectured***

You (like myself) seem to be coming from a J2EE / Spring or Dot NET world where the various frameworks try to address the complete landscape of 2 tier or 3 tier architecture view - model - dao.

Here, the landscape is little different. The frameworks are designed on the principle that do only one thing and do it good. So the overall solution becomes much tougher to arrive at.

So now there are

1. Multiple independent frameworks (node packages) available addressing the same problem space and
2. All these components have to work together to achieve the final big-picture solution.

So there are no crisp boundaries of how the stitching of these packages will be done. Its fluid. And its totally dependent on your peculiar problem. So no generic solutions here and no clear boundaries of what will end where and what will begin where.

You have to decide (and that's hard work). This decision making will be a process where you evolve your architecture instead of creating it upfront in a big bang effort.

It will be met with multiple failures and frustrations in initial days/months.

And then read about **Javascript Fatigue**

***I'm just trying to get my mental-model straight.***

But you are not alone. :) Mine isn't straight either. Not many people in the industry have it straight I can assure you.

Answer (score 1):

Node itself basically lets you write Javascript on the server, and not much else. It has some basic HTTP functions, but I wouldn't want to use those functions alone to make a web app. Express is like the Rails equivalent for the Node ecosystem (with less magic). It handles routing, cookies, and most of your other web-related stuff.

You might want to check out [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect), the de facto standard library for middleware. As for data modeling, most people in the Node world use mongodb with [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/). In practice, you'll end up using Node built-in functions where it makes sense, and plugging in small libraries where you need other functionality. If you have any other questions, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Ok. The most interesting sentence from your post for me is:  'It handles routing, cookies, and most of your other web-related stuff.'. I guess that's where my question is aimed: What's most of my other web-related stuff? What does it do for me and what does it not do. I mentioned the db.. for me that might be 'most of my other...'. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Express will handle routing; request and response hashes, including parameter handling; rendering a response, which can be configured to use a rendering engine like Jade or EJS; cookies; and serving static files ([here are the API docs, for the full list](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html)). If you want to use a database, I'd recommend Mongoose. Since node has `require` and `exports` for defining modules, you can define your models and their methods, and require them in your route handling code to insert them into your templates, or render JSON.

Comment: One more thing, that I forgot to mention: for authentication, I'd recommend [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) -- that's one major component that Express won't handle for you.

Comment: @ajpocus, I would like to clarify your opening statement 'Node itself basically lets you write JavaScript on the server, and not much else' -- Node allows you to do a lot that has nothing to do with running JS on a server, e.g., there are thousands of node command-line utility programs that are not part of a client/server model. Node is a platform containing a JavaScript interpreter that is packaged with a bunch of helper libraries and a command line interface tool -- not **necessarily** associated with running on a server at all.

Comment: @Clark for sure! Thanks for clarifying. I was referring to the Node core, but yeah, I failed to mention the absolute ton of libraries on NPM. I guess it's more accurate to say Node makes Javascript usable outside of the browser (and seriously, the ecosystem is *thriving*, for those reading who haven't dug into [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/)).

Comment: That is definitely true, @ajpocus, and I don't want to be contrary; however, for clarity, even the Node 'core' (built-in modules and interpreter/runtime) isn't necessarily tied to the server, just as the Ruby language/runtime/built-in isn't tied to the server. For example, I could use Node to build a command-line tool that parses command-line input and saves it to a text file -- no client/server model in this use of Node.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, Node is just a JavaScript interpreter, packaged with a bunch of helper libraries and a command line interface tool. Node is packaged with a bunch of utility libraries for performing common development tasks, like interacting with a file system or sending an HTTP request. **Connect** is an abstraction on-top of Node, providing a middleware layer. **Express** is an abstraction on-top of **Connect** & **Node**, that makes it easier to build certain types of applications, primarily web applications that use http, websockets, complex routing, session and cookie management, authentication, etc.

There are some competitors at the 'same level of abstraction' as **Express** — one of the more popular is **Hapi** (very similar to express), and if you are looking for a Rails-like framework on-top of Node, then look at SailsJS, Locomotive, or Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Express speeds up your development effort and helps to better structure the layout of the code for you.
If you are new to node.js, you can build an express server in no time with minimum effort. It is also easily extendible.
Usually people use a few others popular node-modules in conjunction with express-- connect, passport, ejs, body-parser, connect-redis, mongoose etc depending on what your usage scenarios are and what integration you have with
other servers.

Answer (score 0):

As an analogy:

`express` is to `node`  as

- asp.net is to .NET
- j2ee is to java
- ...

Express is just server side middleware framework implemented in javascript executed by the V8 javascript engine on the server side.